# xpath find text within a table

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am trying to find and select the text "Paris" within a dynamic table. When I run my selenium tests it can find the table and it can verify the text "Paris" exists however it cannot click Paris

I think it's something like this:

```
/html/body/div[class='yui-dt-liner']/td/tr[contains 'Paris']/div
```

Or:

```
//div[class='yui-dt-liner']/table/tr[contains text(), "Paris"]/div
```

But I can't get it to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the *"cannot click Paris"* part (very much a Selenium specific type of question), both expression you'd provide are not sintactically correct.

Probably, they should be:

```
/html/body/div[@class='yui-dt-liner']/table/tr/td[contains(.,'Paris')]/div
```

And

```
//div[@class='yui-dt-liner']/table/tr/td[contains(.,'Paris')]/div
```

**Note**: `@` abbreviated form of `attribute::` axis. Correct `contains()` function syntax. You should better use the string value of the element (`.` is the abbreviated form of `self::node()`) instead of the first text node child.

Comment: thanks, figured it out selenium.click("//div[text()='Paris']");